# ClearCase equivalent of git status

Tags: version-control, clearcase, git-status

With git (and other revision control apps like mercurial), you have a "status" functionality for a repository, which lists the repo files which are Modified, Deleted, Moved, Added or Missing.

How do we achieve the same in ClearCase (relative to the non-checked-out version chosen by the configspec currently in effect)?

The best I have so far is listing the files with modifications using ct diff and grep'ping for `---`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Anything related to file status is usually managed by [`cleartool l`s](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm)

```
cleartool ls -r -l -vis
```

You can also add `--view-only` to restricts the listing to objects that belong logically to the view: view-private files, view-private directories, and view-private links; checked-out versions; and all derived objects visible in the view.

But I suspect some kind of post-processing (`grep`/`awk`) will be needed to get exactly what you want.

You have an example in [`bmpenuelas/gfcc`](https://github.com/bmpenuelas/gfcc)

> ```
> gfcc status
> ```

> clearcase actions: List all new or modified files.
> `cleartool ls -rec -view_only` to get new files.
> `cleartool lsco -cview -a -s` to get all the checked out files, then find those which have been actually modified with `cleartool diff -predecessor`.

So a *better* `git status` equivalent is, according to this project, a bit more involved.

Comment: gfcc is very interesting, although tricky on machines with no python. Your first command really doesn't do what I want...

Comment: @einpoklumYes, I though a simple `ct ls` might not be enough, which is why I mentioned the `gfcc` project. Even if you don't have python, you can get, from its sources, what is needed to emulate a `git status` (through a combination of `ct ls`, `ct lsco` and `ct diff`)

Comment: I might write a shell script for this with some text processing like you suggest. If I do, I'll post it here.

Comment: @einpoklum That would be great!